# Why do I have to use <T> on static method call on a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

Im following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx) example of a generic class.
Because I did not want to fill the main function of my project with test code I wanted to create a static showcase function which runs an example of the code.

my code:

```
namespace Syntax
{
    public class GenericClass<T>
    {
        private class Node
        {
            private T data;
            private Node next;

            public Node(T t)
            {
                next = null;
                data = t;
            }

            public Node Next { get { return next; } set { next = value; } }
            public T Data { get { return data; } set { data = value; } }
        }


        private Node head;
        public GenericClass()
        {
            head = null;
        }

        public void AddHead(T t)
        {
            Node n = new Node(t);
            n.Next = head;
            head = n;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            Node current = head;
            while (current != null)
            {
                yield return current.Data;
                current = current.Next;
            }
        }


        public static void Showcase()
        {
            GenericClass<int> list = new GenericClass<int>();

            for(int x = 0; x <10; x++)
            {
                list.AddHead(x);
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("\nPrinting generic class using ints.");
            foreach (int i in list)
            {
                System.Console.Write(i + ", ");
            }

            GenericClass<char> listChars = new GenericClass<char>();
            string abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw";
            foreach (char c in abc)
            {
                listChars.AddHead(c);
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("\n\nPrinting generic class using chars.");
            foreach (var c in listChars)
            {
                System.Console.Write(c + ", ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's almost exactly the same as the linked example except the static Showcase method.

Now in my main method I can call:

```
GenericClass<int>.Showcase();
```

I could change the code with:

```
GenericClass<string>.Showcase();
GenericClass<char>.Showcase();
```

And it would still work.

If I could do

```
GenericClass<int> test = new GenericClass<int>();
test.Showcase();
```

It would make total sense to me that it would require a type as I could call other methods on test.

I dont see the advanges of adding the type, the need to add a random class can only lead to confusion in my mind, why isnt the syntax for static methods `genericClass<T>.StaticMethod();` for example as adding a type to the static method dosnt add anythig (or does it?). So why do I need to use `<T>` when calling a static method on a generic class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you haven't created a class called `GenericClass`, you've created an open generic class called `GenericClass<T>`.

There is nothing to stop you from also creating a class `GenericClass` in the same namespace, and nothing to stop you from creating also a class called `GenericClass<T1,T2>`. All of these could exist in the same namespace and have no explicit or implicit relationship between them, unless you declare one.

So, if you want to invoke a static method on "the GenericClass class that is generic in one type parameter", you've got to say that somehow, and you've found how to do it - by supplying a type parameter.

One could argue that, if the static method doesn't use the type parameter, it's redundant - so why can you not call it just by using the still-open type parameter? Well, firstly because that would have to be new syntax to allow that to happen<sup>1</sup>. And second, what happens if your method accesses any static fields? With generic types, each unique type used as the type parameter causes a new set of static fields to exist.

---

> why isnt the syntax for static methods `genericClass<T>.StaticMethod();` for example as ...

The above was added after my initial answer and I'd hoped this was already addressed in footnote 1 below. But in case it's not clear, this simple syntax won't work. You need to invent some new syntax because you might have:

```
class Abc<T> {
   void DoSomething(){
       GenericClass<T>.StaticMethod();
   }
}
```

or

```
namespace X {
   class T {
   }
   class Abc {
      void DoSomething(){
          GenericClass<T>.StaticMethod();
      }
   }
}
```

In both of the above examples `T` is already defined by the outer scope. So you need some other way of saying "I don't want to supply a type for the first type parameter of this generic".

---

<sup>1</sup>E.g. being able to say `GenericClass<T>.Showcase`. Any new syntax to allow it couldn't be so straightforward. Because a) there may be a generic type parameter `T` in scope in the calling context, or b) the name of the generic type parameter may clash with some other type name that is in scope in the calling context.

Comment: Thanks for the explenation, coul you add an example of " And second, what happens if your method accesses any static fields? With generic types, each unique type used as the type parameter causes a new set of static fields to exist.". Thats the argument for me so far that makes the most sense.

Comment: @SvenB - if you have any instance of a `GenericClass<int>` and it accesses a static field, it's sharing that static field with all other instances of `GenericClass<int>`. But that specific variable isn't the same as the one that would be accessed by a `GenericClass<float>`. Static methods can also access these same fields but it needs to know what "type" of generic it is to know which static field to access.

Comment: @SvenB - I've added examples of the point I'd hoped was already made in footnote one about why you cannot have the simple syntax you're looking for (even ignoring the other reasons)

Answer (score 5):

Because the class is generic and so using it requires a type argument, even if the static method itself is non-generic. Type arguments are not optional.

This is why having a static member on a generic class results in [CA1000](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182139.aspx) — because doing so requires you to provide a type argument even when it's ultimately irrelevant to that static member. If you want to create static methods that are related to your generic class, put them in a non-generic helper class.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a non generic class with the *same* name

```
public class GenericClass {
            public static void Showcase()
        {
            // your method
        }
}
```

on top of the generic, possibly derived, class

```
public class GenericClass<T> : GenericClass
```

So that you can simply call

```
    GenericClass.Showcase();
```

They're actually two different classes but their naming convention make them strongly related. Your original `Showcase` is really fully qualified as a `<T>.Showcase` and that explains why you were forced to specify a type.

**Edit**

> for example as adding a type to the static method dosnt add anythig (or does it?)

You can generalize the method by specifying a *conversion* between the generic `T` type and the `int` you're currently using

For example, if you define

```
public class GenericClass<T> 
{

    public static void Showcase(Func<int,T> conv, Func<T,int> inv)
```

then you'll write

```
        GenericClass<T> list = new GenericClass<T>();

        for(int x = 0; x <10; x++)
        {
            list.AddHead(conv(x));
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("\nPrinting generic class using ints.");
        foreach (T i in list)
        {
            System.Console.Write(inv(i) + ", ");
        }
```

and the usage would be (when `T` is a `string`)

```
GenericClass<string>.Showcase(x => x.ToString(),int.Parse);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method is allowed to use the `T` of its containing class. For example:

```
class GenericClass<T> where T : new()
{
  public static T GetOne()
  {
    return new T();
  }
}
```

With that you could say `GenericClass<StringBuilder>.GetOne();` to get a new `StringBuilder`, or `GenericClass<int>.GetOne();` to get a zero integer.

For an example in the Base Class Library, there is `Comparer<StringBuilder>.Create(...)` which is something else than `Comparer<int>.Create(...)`.

Another issue is if the method uses a `static` field. There will be one "copy" of the `static` field per substitution for `T` with an actual type. The method would need to know which `T` it had.

Similarly if the method calls another `static` method which uses `T` or other static stuff.

---

Just because your particular method happens to not use `T` or any other `static` members of the class, you still have to specify what `T` is. This is for the same reason that you have to specify a method parameter even if the method happens not to use that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> why do I need to use `<T>` when calling a static method on a generic class?

Because a generic class is a "blueprint". Static members are shared per constructed type.

Consider this generic class:

```
public class Generic<T>
{
    public static string Bar { get; set; }  
}
```

Then using it like this:

```
Generic<string>.Bar = "Baz";
Generic<bool>.Bar = "Qux";

Console.WriteLine(Generic<string>.Bar);
Console.WriteLine(Generic<bool>.Bar);
```

Will print "Baz", followed by "Qux".

Comment: I understand, but I could add Generic<SomeReallyUnrelatedClass>.Bar = "Foo"; that would not make much sense to me but still works. I understand the 'blueprint' requires a type but the syntax is random/confusing as adding a type dosn't change any of the results.

Comment: @SvenB If you added `System.Console.WriteLine(default(T));` inside your `Showcase()` method, what should happen if `T` was unknown. Or if you added `System.Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);`?

Comment: @Sven _"adding a type dosn't change any of the results"_ - yes it does. The static member lives once for each `T`. So if your static method uses a static field or property, it may be showing very unexpected behavior. If you want to omit it, what should the compiler fill in for `T`, `object`? What if that conflicts with existing code that _does_ use the `Generic<object>.Bar` for something?